# Real path to config.ini in python binary *app in MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyinstaller

I have this code:

```
def _read_config(self):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.sections()
   # I tried 
    path_main = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
   # and this after create exec file with pyinstaller nothing changed
    path_main = os.getcwd() 
    print(path_main)
    file = os.path.join(path_main, "config.ini")
    print(file)
    config.read(file)
    return config
```

When I run the code in MacOS using the terminal with `python gui.py`, it prints this:

```
/Users/telos/Desktop/Telos-Monitor-Tool/client
/Users/telos/Desktop/Telos-Monitor-Tool/client/config.ini
```

But when I do `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed gui.py`, I receive 1 app file, when I run it I get this:

```
/Users/telos
/Users/telos/config.ini
```

But the one file app and ``gui.py` is in the same directory.

So I have an error because the Python parser can't find config.ini.

As in comennt discasion advise me to use `print(QtCore.QCoreApplication.applicationDirPath())` after recreating app, i have 2 file 1 `gui.app`, 2-nd `gui.exec`. `gui.exec` find config.ini fine and all work fine, but `gui.app` can't and send the error.

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: I don't see a call to `os.getcwd()` in your code.

Comment: changes with `os.getcwd()` but try and `getcwd()` and that way, same

Comment: The working directory isn’t the directory the script/executable is in, it’s the directory you were in when you run it. If you’re in /Users/telos when you run it (either version), that’s what its working directory will be.

Comment: How i can check where the app situated? from Python?

Comment: have you read the question ,`path_main =os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` i tried,  same as` getcwd` after i created exec file for mac the application can't find config And return `/Users/telos/config.ini` but config `/Users/telos/Desktop/Telos-Monitor-Tool/client/config.ini`

Comment: In what folder is the binary?

Comment: `/Users/telos/Desktop/Telos-Monitor-Tool/client`

Comment: But this command in  binary `path_main = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`  print `/Users/telos/config.ini` as result error cause in that folder no that file

Comment: @Hellbea `print(QtCore.QCoreApplication.applicationDirPath())`

Comment: @eyllanesc print(QtCore.QCoreApplication.applicationDirPath()) you are my Hero, work. post the nswer i will confirm

Comment: @Hellbea I can not since your question is closed, delete this question and publish a new one stating that your application is done in PyQt5 and I can publish an answer.

Comment: @Hellbea I reopened this question.  Please edit it to provide all of the relevant information.  You can then prompt the people who helped you to provide an answer for posterity, or answer it yourself if you feel confident you can provide an explanation.

Comment: @eyllanesc Edited question how you can post answer and i edit have new problem. Thx for help

Comment: @Hellbea 
You say you have an error, what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using PyQt5 if you want to get the executable folder you can use:

```
QtCore.QCoreApplication.applicationDirPath()
```

Comment: do you know why exec run and find file normally and app no, have two file in pyinstaller  dist directory?

Comment: @Hellbea I do not have mac, I have tried it in linux and windows, in the case of linux it generates a .elf and in the case of windows it generates an .exe that are executable, in the case of mac I suppose that it should generate you only an executable , I do not understand why you have 2 outputs, on the other hand if you are going to manage setting I recommend using QSettings, with that class you only have to establish some minimum configurations and he creates the .ini in the generic place.

Comment: @Hellbea the path used by QSettings does not depend on the executable.

Comment: me too windows and linux oerfect decision, but mac os dont want to work corectly

Comment: @Hellbea The applications that I did work for mac but I do not use ConfigParser but QSettings, to use it you only have to set `QCoreApplication.setOrganizationXXX()`, as it indicates it will create the config file in the correct place that depends on the OS, and not on the app. For more information read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html

Comment: I guees it is only sane desicion for mac os.